# Need help on to execution plan in SQL Server in Type Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, lateral-join

I am getting below warnings in execution plan. Please some provide suggestions on how to resolve this error.

**Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(int,STRING_SPLIT.[value],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice**

[image]

Above warning in seen for below SQL Statement

```
SELECT TE.value AS GroupID
    ,ISNULL(TM.TotalCount, 0) AS GroupCount
FROM #tblWorkQueueDocuemnt TM
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) AS value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4', ',')
    ) TE ON TM.GroupID = TE.value
```

#tblWorkQueueDocuemnt : Statement for Create Table.
CREATE TABLE #tblWorkQueueDocuemnt (GroupID INT, TotalCount INT)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the warning message indicates that, because of the type conversion, an index cannot be used in the derived table. I don't think that it really matters here, because the derived table itself is based on a parsed literal string - so there cannot be an index whatsoever.

As a side note: do you really need to pass this value as a literal CSV string? If would be simpler to build a proper derived table with `values()`, like so:

```
select te.value as groupid, coalesce(tm.totalcount, 0) as groupcount
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)) as te(groupid)
left join #tblworkqueuedocuemnt tm on tm.tm.groupid = te.value
```

Incidently, this would avoid the warning (there is no conversion needed, as values are given with the proper datatype to start with). But, again, I don't think you shoud worry about that warning.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old thing they have whenever they have an implicit conversion.

In instances where you are doing an implicit conversion on a field, it may not be able to use the index. Similar to if you did an explicit CAST or CONVERT on it.

If it's running fine and has no problems, ignore it.

See e.g., https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/we-need-to-talk-about-the-warnings-in-your-query-plans/

In your case, you could explicitly cast the values after the string_split as ints, if desired. It is technically cleaner but probably won't improve performance at all.

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) AS value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4', ',')
```

I get the same warning:

[image]

But changing `CONVERT(INT, value)` to `PARSE(value AS int)`:

```sql
SELECT PARSE(value AS int) AS value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,4', ',')
```

Removes the warning:

[image]